# Still Under Suspension :-(

Tags: discussion, suspensions

It has been couple of months where my account where suspended due to one of my "controversial" comments. All I said was its not 80s anymore and the readability and documentation of your code is more important than the size of your code. Right or wrong I did deleted it and still waiting to get out of suspension. How many more months I need to wait for this?

Comment: I can't see any reason why you would be banned from asking questions; but then again, I can't see deleted questions. How many deleted questions have you asked?

Answer (score 11):

Your account is not and has never been suspended by a moderator. If you were suspended, your reputation would have been locked at 1 and you couldn't have posted this Meta question (or do anything else but read the site). No idea why you think we (mods) would suspend you - or anyone else - for a single comment. We typically only intervene when there's a repeating pattern of abuse, and when we do, we typically send a warning first.

That said, your account has been automatically blocked from asking questions by the system. There's no time limit on automatic blocks, if you don't follow the advice given in the [linked article](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans) in the block message, your account will remain blocked. This is completely up to you, there's nothing any one of us can do to help.